# How to get attribute css of class in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, class, nuxt.js

I can't get attribute css of class in Vuejs/nuxtjs in my project.

My class: 'only-small' has attribute: 'display:none'  if mediaquery  <768.

If this way is impossible, can someone suggest another method to resolve my problem without using window object (window.innerWidth always error if refesh page - window is not defined) and vue-screen plugin

size.vue :

> in viewport < 768

```
<button class="select-btn select-btn--size only-small">
       <span class="select-btn__label"></span>
       <svg class="icon icon--down">
             <use xlink:href="/global.svg#down"></use>
       </svg>
</button>
```

> in viewport >= 768

```
<div class="select size-select small-font only-large size-select--small">
        <div class="select__headline"></div>
        <div class="select__items no-scrollbar">
            <div>
                <button class="select__label" ></button>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

> info.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Size></Size> 
    <AddToCart></AddToCart>
  </div>
</template
```

> scss:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .only-small {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

1. click add to cart  with  viewport < 768: do some action
2. click add to cart with viewport > 768: do some other action

When I resize the viewport, no class, element,... is added or removed. Only attribute of css applies.

Comment: Are you trying to use viewport size to conditionally apply a class to the element and then select the `.only-small` elements to hide them? If so, you can use vue-mq (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-media-queries) to help with your conditional rendering.

Comment: thank you very much, but it is not work like vue-screen plugin

Answer (score 1):

Actually, i didn't understand exactly what you need. But, if you want to show your elements according to visitor mediaquery you can use v-show directive with a computed property.

```
<button v-show="mediaQuery" class="select-btn select-btn--size only-small">
   <span class="select-btn__label"></span>
   <svg class="icon icon--down">
         <use xlink:href="/global.svg#down"></use>
   </svg>
```

```
<div v-show="!mediaQuery" class="select size-select small-font only-large size-select--small">
    <div class="select__headline"></div>
    <div class="select__items no-scrollbar">
        <div>
            <button class="select__label" ></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
data() {
return {
  mediaQuery: true
}
```

},

```
 computed: {
checkMedia() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(min-width:768px')) {
    this.mediaQuery = false
  }
},
```